# AirflowSkipException with PythonVirtualenvOperator

Tags: python, airflow

i'm trying to set skipped state to the task programmatically in airflow. I know there is AirflowSkipException that can be used to set tasks to skipped state, however i'm using PythonVirtualenvOperator and in that case task is set to failed instead of skipped.

Code example looks like this

```
   def execute():
      a = 0
      if a > 0:
        print('continue running task')
      else: 
        raise AirflowSkipException
    
    def execute_task():
      return PythonVirtualenvOperator(
        task_id='test skipping',
        op_kwargs={},
        python_callable=execute,
        provide_context=True,
        system_site_packages=True,
        dag=dag
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

The `AirflowSkipException` cause your problem because the exception is raised inside the virtual environment and so it does not go out and propagate back to the `Airflow` process.

Lets use a `PythonOperator` and manually create a virtual environment inside your execute function so that it goes to `Airflow`.

Here is how you can do it:

```
import subprocess
import sys
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowSkipException
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

def execute():
    a = 0
    if a > 0:
        print('continue running task')
    else:
        raise AirflowSkipException

def execute_task_with_venv():
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "venv", "myenv"])
    subprocess.check_call(["./myenv/bin/pip", "install", "-r", "requirements.txt"])

    execute()

execute_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='test_skipping',
    python_callable=execute_task_with_venv,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
)
```